# Java Class.getSimpleName() and .getName() behaving differently on Cacao versus Sun Java

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Does any one have any idea why this would be happening?

This is some modified lines from the Java DBus bindings (2.6)

```
  // don't let people import things which don't have a
  // valid D-Bus interface name
  System.out.println("type.getName: " + type.getName() + "   type.getSimpleName: " + type.getSimpleName() );
  if (type.getName().equals(type.getSimpleName()))  {
      throw new DBusException(_("DBusInterfaces cannot be declared outside a package: " + "type.getName: " + type.getName()
              + "   type.getSimpleName: " + type.getSimpleName() ));
  }
```

Now check out the difference in output from Cacao (0.99.4) versus Sun 1.5

```
@ubuntu:~/tmp/cacao$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_16"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_16-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_16-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

@ubuntu:~/tmp/cacao$ cacao -version
java version "1.5.0"
CACAO version 0.99.3+hg

java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/classpath:/ho... DBusChat 

type.getName: org.freedesktop.DBus   type.getSimpleName: DBus
...Exception in thread "main" org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusExecutionException: Could not get owner of name 'framez.tests.dbus.DbusChatInterface': no such name
```

versus...

```
 cacao -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/classpath:/ho... DBusChat
 type.getName: org.freedesktop.DBus   type.getSimpleName: org.freedesktop.DBus
```

The Exception is unimportant - its being caused by this behavior... Any ideas? Or is this some weird bug with Cacao.

Does anyone know if .getName() is a VM dependent thing?

Info:

GNU Classpath 0.98 on both JVMs
DBus bindings 2.6

Comment: Your sing the "wrong" mechanism to figure out if a class is a standalone or inner class.getEnclosingClass() etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the port of GNU Classpath to the Cacao platform.  If I recall correctly, most of the methods in the Classpath version of `java.lang.Class` delegate to a "vm" class that needs to be implemented for each port of the library.

Certainly `Class.getSimpleName()` should return the classname without the package qualification.

Comment: This is a classpath bug. Confirmed the cacao team. Its a simple fix in vm.reference.java.lang.VMClass.

Comment: There seems to be a renewed interest in GNU classpath recently, and as a result there is a patch for this problem in CVS, finally: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/classpath/classpath/vm/reference/java/lang/VMClass.java?r1=1.21&r2=1.22

Comment: The last comment was wishful thinking.  [He's dead Jim!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt5zD_6n-eA) :-)